# Create custom fields with apex

Tags: apex

Anybody knows how to create custom text fields on salesforce.com objects using apex?

Answer (score 14):

You can do that by using the metadata API and a web service written by [Andrew Fawcett](https://twitter.com/andyinthecloud) that you can find [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes).

Example:

```
MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Test__c.TestField__c';
customField.label = 'Test Field';
customField.type_x = 'Text';
customField.length = 42;
MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results =   service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { customField });
```

And here is the [original thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008z8gIAA).

Comment: On the last line, you refer to a variable called `service` but this has not been defined.

Answer (score 11):

As a technical evolution, Salesforce has made very easy to create the field by using tooling api...

For example-

```
String objectapiname = 'Content_Item__c';//replace with your object name
String fieldapiname = 'Country_Name';//replace with your field name
String fieldlabel = 'Country_Name';//replace with your field label
String fielddescription = 'Country Name';//replace with your field label

HttpRequest requestinside = new HttpRequest();
requestinside.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
requestinside.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
requestinside.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/');
requestinside.setMethod('POST');
String fieldDef = '{"Metadata" : ';
String metadef = '"type" : "Text","description" : "'+fielddescription+'", "inlineHelpText" : "","precision" : null,"label" : "'+fieldlabel+'","length" : 255,"required" : false'; //added missing semi-colon
fieldDef += '{'+metadef+'},';
fieldDef += '"FullName" : "'+objectapiname+'.'+fieldapiname+'__c"}';
system.debug(fieldDef);
requestinside.setBody(fieldDef);
HTTPResponse res = http.send(requestinside);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

https://sfdcian.com/apex-code-to-create-custom-field-programmatically/

Comment: Thanks man! Converted to python version in case if anyone needs it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332251/how-to-create-custom-field-via-api

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks for posting python version.

Comment: this is the best answer by a mile. One small change would be to create a Metadata class and JSON.serialize() it instead of building the JSON by hand. Other than that, great answer.