# Create/Update a new section in Visualforce page based on input provided in a custom field

Tags: apex, visualforce, api

I have a custom object, say `VF_Page_Update__c` which has say, a `picklist field` called VF_Page_Name. This field will contain the names of some VF Pages say A,B,C,D. I also have another text field in this object called `Update__c`.

What I require is, say I write 'Test' in the `Update__c` field and choose A as the VF page Name. Then a new field will be created in the A Visualforce Page with 'Test' as the data.

Is this possible? Do I require the use of any API? If anyone is able to do this, can you please share the code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be possible using [metadata api](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes), with wrapper service written by [Andrew Fawcett](https://twitter.com/andyinthecloud).

Refer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56421/create-custom-fields-with-apex) and [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/using-meta-data-api-in-apex) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rahul, I've already gone through it, but I find everything very vague and don't know how it relates to my particular situation. Can anyone provide a more detailed answer as to how to go about this.

Comment: Code should not be that difficult. Can you share what you have tried so far?