# How to create and add custom fields to existing custom object programmatically using apex?

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, dynamic

I've looked around for this and there seem to be a couple of different ways on how to do this.

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000Qw4ZQAS
- [Create custom fields with apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56421/create-custom-fields-with-apex)

However, all of these seem to be old ways (I might be completely wrong here and those methods can be totally valid today) but I'd like to make sure I'm using the latest method for doing this and avoid making a request like it's suggested in one of the StackExchange answers in the link above (The tooling API method). I also don't want to implement this in a Visual Force or any UI pages, I'd like to create custom fields on an existing object based on a received post request.

A simple example for what I'm trying to do:

```
for (String fieldName : fieldNameList)
{
   Existing_Custom_Object__c.CreateNewCustomField(name = fieldName, type = checkbox, ...);
   // Upload/Push this change to the org
}
```

Comment: You cannot mutate the schema of your org without calling either the Metadata or Tooling APIs. The linked question remains valid. The OOTB Apex Metadata API does not support Custom Fields.

Comment: Sorry what's OOTB?

Comment: What's the difference between the two methods in this SE post? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56421/create-custom-fields-with-apex
 Please give some more information to understand how it's done or even a reference link to a the official docs? Thanks!

Comment: Tooling API requires substantially less code. I am not aware of any official documentation beyond the Tooling API [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm) reference.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidReed!

Comment: @Bahman.A "OOTB" is short for "out of the box". This means something provided as standard. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature)) for more.